# Localize auto-generated columns of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to localize the auto-generated columns created by DataGrid? 
If I try to use the

`[DisplayName(Properties.Resources.UnitsLabel)]` attribute I get a compile time error saying that the attribute value must be a compile time constant.